# Distinguish presenter from authors

Tags: beamer

I am giving a talk about a paper and I am not an author. I would like to make this distinction in the slides but I am not sure if this is possible without modifying the standard beamer class too much.

Comment: The main issue is: how exactly should the distinction be made?

Comment: Changing the background color should be easy, even with beamer.

Comment: Perhaps add the authors to the title? As in "On 'P is equal to NP' by Smith and Jones". Then show you as the author of the presentation.